# Explore Running Rails Server Environment from Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, rails-console

I have an app, and I have it running locally. I can create another version of the app in `rails console`, however I want to have a command line interface for the app that is running that I can interact with both in the web interface and the console.

Ideally I fire up `rails s` and then can play with the variables in that environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this with vanilla Rails. Each time you type `rails` (whether with `server` or `console`), you're booting a brand new instance of your application, which shares no state with any other instance.

However, if you install the extremely useful [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) gem, you can type `binding.pry` at any point in your application (inside an action or model or view). When program flow hits your `binding.pry`, the **server** instance will drop into an interactive shell, and you can inspect the state of your server process. This is about as close as you can get to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @meager - I owe you a vote on this.  Give me two hours and you'll get a 1-up from me. :)

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: @ElijahMurray Just remember that your server will be blocked until you stop your `pry` session. Your browser will hang until it eventually times out. To stop your interactive `pry`ing, hit `ctrl-d`.

Comment: I love `pry`!!! Exactly what I was looking for, and obviously there's a lot I can explore with it. Would think something like this would be in vanilla rails though!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, this is common to do.

You can have `rails s` running in one terminal window within your app directory, then have `rails c` running in another terminal window within the same app directory.

You can then modify objects in the DB which will be visible within the web UI.

Comment: I thought that's how it worked--maybe I'm not doing something right? I start the server, then I start the console, but if I check if my objects exist in the console (objects created through the web UI), they don't. ie an `application` model is created through the UI, but when I call `application` or `@application` it doesn't exist in the console.

Comment: @Elijah No, as you said in the question, the console and server are two completely separate instances of your application.

Comment: Right - all variables are local to the UI, and more specifically, that thread of action within the UI.  For example, if you create a `User` in the application and store it as `@user`, you could find this user in console by doing `User.last`.

Comment: See @meagar's answer - this will allow you to stop the app midstream and check variables.  `pry` is awesome - highly recommend it.  My answer will allow you to mess with data and then have that data show up on subsequent loads of pages on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to "I love `pry`!!!" - you are generally asking how to "debug" your app. So, if you install RubyMine (and a handful gems such as debug_inspector, debugger, debugger-linecache, debugger-ruby_core_source, pry-debugger, & ruby-debug-ide), then you can run your `rails server` from RubyMine's debugging Configuration.

From there, you can put a breakpoint where you would have pry-ed. And you can run statements in RubyMine, to see what's going on. And RubyMine makes an awesome platform for refactoring and automated testing. No affiliation; just providing more answers for the question.